# Could not start GlassFish SERVERE: CORE10012 Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more

Tags: glassfish-3

When i deleted the projects that i deployed once in the past,
i could not start the server because of this error:

> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
>
> INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
>   3.1.2.2 (build 5)
>
> INFO: Registered
>   org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for
>   persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
>
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 125ms - bound to
>   [0.0.0.0:8181]
>
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 109ms - bound to
>   [0.0.0.0:4848]
>
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 31ms - bound to
>   [0.0.0.0:7676]
>
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 125ms - bound to
>   [0.0.0.0:3700]
>
> INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
>
> SEVERE: CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its
>   original location any more: 
>   file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/2796/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/mavenprojectJSF/target/mavenprojectJSF-1.0-SNAPSHOT/
>
> SEVERE: CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its
>   original location any more:
>   file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/2796/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/jsf1/build/web/
>
> SEVERE: CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its
>   original location any more:
>   file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/2796/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/struts/build/web/
>
> SEVERE: CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its
>   original location any more:
>   file:/D:/self%20learning%202014/struts2/Struts2-ExecAndWait-Interceptor-Example/Struts2Example/target/Struts2Example/
>
> INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (5) startup time :
>   Felix (2,078ms), startup services(1,422ms), total(3,500ms)
>
> SEVERE: Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port
>   within range:
>   8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@14fccd
>
> INFO: Server shutdown initiated
>
> INFO: Already stopped, so just returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the file

> domain.xml

In

> C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1

And removed the **application** tags of **xml** and **application-ref** tags too for those projects mentioned above.

And i deleted the projects folder when i searched inside the glassfish folder
in 
--> domains folder --> applications folder

To make it as i never deployed any personal project with it.

This way you are undeploying the applications on server without starting it that what was causing the error

Comment: please specify the reason of -1

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem under Glassfish 4.1 after having migrated from Netbeans 8.2 to IntelliJ Idea.

To solve this problem I have only deleted application tags in `domain.xml` file.

I have deleted lines commented in following code

```
  <applications>
    <!-- TO-DELETE
    <application context-root="/tlga" object-type="user" name="web" directory-deployed="true" location="file:/C:/GIT_SOURCES/TLGA-Web/web/target/tlga-1.18-SNAPSHOT/">
      <property name="archiveType" value="war"></property>
      <property name="appLocation" value="file:/C:/GIT_SOURCES/TLGA-Web/web/target/tlga-1.18-SNAPSHOT/"></property>
      <property name="org.glassfish.ejb.container.application_unique_id" value="100406159636627456"></property>
      <property name="org.glassfish.persistence.app_name_property" value="web"></property>
      <property name="defaultAppName" value="tlga-1.18-SNAPSHOT"></property>
      <module name="web">
        <engine sniffer="ejb"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="security"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="webservices"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="weld"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="jpa"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="web"></engine>
      </module>
    </application>
    <application context-root="/tlga" object-type="user" directory-deployed="true" name="tlga-1.17.3" location="file:/C:/GIT_SOURCES/TLGA-WEB/web/target/tlga-1.17.3/">
      <property name="archiveType" value="war"></property>
      <property name="appLocation" value="file:/C:/GIT_SOURCES/TLGA-WEB/web/target/tlga-1.17.3/"></property>
      <property name="org.glassfish.ejb.container.application_unique_id" value="100519021875888128"></property>
      <property name="org.glassfish.persistence.app_name_property" value="tlga-1.17.3"></property>
      <property name="defaultAppName" value="tlga-1.17.3"></property>
      <module name="tlga-1.17.3">
        <engine sniffer="ejb"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="security"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="webservices"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="weld"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="jpa"></engine>
        <engine sniffer="web"></engine>
      </module>
    </application>
    -->
  </applications>
```

For me, DOMAIN.XML file is located in another location. To find it, I have searched to  DOMAIN.XML files in `c:\Glassfish.4.1\glassfish\domains` folder.

I have deleted the 2 existing "/tlga" domains. Removing only one doesn't resolve my issue.

**Explanation of how this error occurs:**

These 2 <application> tags has been automatically generated by IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2018.2 !!! The first time I have deployed tlga-1.17.3, I don't have encountered any problem.

But this version was PRODUCTION version!

I have then switched GIT environment from PRODUCTION to DEVELOPMENT. I have build new release and started application again.

I suppose that IntelliJ has added a second <application> tag in `domain.xml` file and started again Glassfish that has refused to start !